# Chunkwise-Copy data from InputStream to OutputStream + getting byte[] at the end

Tags: java, stream, guava, apache-commons

I know how to copy chunkwise from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

I know how to get an `byte[]` from an `InputStream`.

But how to combine them in one step? Is there an OutputStream that can be piped *and* buffers all written bytes so it can return a byte[] at the end?

I need something like an `ByteArrayOutputStream` but one that can be piped. (e.g. to a FileOutputStream)

Or I need something like a `MultiOutputStream` which can forward to multiple OutputStreams.
Solutions using Guava and/or Apache Commons are prefered. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably have a look at the `TeeOutputStream` of Apache: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html

Comment: +1 nice catch. Would never guessed the name of this Stream. :-)

Comment: Checked implementation of TeeOutputStream and it fails to close the branch stream when the main stream throws a Throwable (e.g. IOException) at close() call. I've written my own MultiOutputStream and I will upload it to GitHub later.

Comment: this is why link only answers suck, the link is dead

Comment: The only missing words are : "yes, you can use that class". The TeeOutputStream was a valid answer at the time of writing. The question was "which class can I use?" And the answer is "this one". So what are you ranting about?

Comment: Furthermore finding the updated link is rather easy. Now that I'm in front of an desktop, it took me... wow... 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the OutputStream and create a custom MultiOutputStream by wrapping (like decorator) over two internal streams (ByteArrayOutputStream and FileOutputStream). You can take both streams as constructor args. Overwrite the appropriate write methods and write to both destination streams.

e.g. something like

```
  class MultiOuputStream extends OutputStream {

   private OutputStream stream1; 
   private OutputStream stream2;

   public MultiOuputStream(){
    // can throw exception, not supported
   }

   public MultiOuputStream(OutputStream stream1, OutputStream stream2){
     this.stream1 = stream1;
     this.stream2 = stream2;
   }

   @Override
   public write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
     stream1.write(bytes);
     stream2.write(bytes);
   }

   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Valid answer, of course. But I still hope that I do not have to write one of my own.

Answer (score 1):

I considered using [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html), but its close()-Method lacks closing the branch stream when closing the main stream throws an Exception.
So I have to close the branch stream on my own when an Exception occured. Due to the concept of java's stream chaining this is very impractical.
Since this behaviour is not at least documented I call this a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-303).

This is not really an issue when I would use ByteArrayOutputStream as one of the streams the TeeOutputStreams branches to. But this is only because [ByteArrayOutputStreams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close%28%29) must not be closed.

That's why I've written [MultiOutputStream](https://github.com/fabian-barney/Utils/blob/master/utils/src/com/barney4j/utils/io/MultiOutputStream.java). It is very similar to TeeOutputStream but goes on closing its underlying streams even when Exceptions raised in between. Additionally it allows multiple branch streams and not only one.

**Edit**
The bug in TeeOutputStream was fixed today. It will be released with Commons IO 2.2.